# A base class for lazy static classes

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to write a base class which implements the basic structure of a lazy static pattern.

```
public class LazyStatic<T>
{
    private static T _static;
    public static T Static
    {
        get
        {
            if (_static == null) _static = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            return _static;
        }
    }
}
```

Once I am done with this base class, I would use it like

```
public class MyOtherClass : LazyStatic<MyOtherClass>
{
  ...
}
```

Is the base class correctly implemented?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a technical term, and should be avoided by programmers.

Comment: why would you inherit a static class? - Also what's wrong with [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Since you haven't stated what this code actually needs to do, we can't tell you whether it successfully meets its needs or not.

Comment: Doesn't [Lazy<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that `T` has a parameterless constructor, but you don't [restrict you generic class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) so that the compiler knows that:

```
public class LazyStatic<T> where T : new()
{
    private static T _static;
    public static T Static
    {
        get
        {
            if (_static == null) _static = new T();
            return _static;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Could you please explain the `where T : new()` of your implementation?

Comment: @Saphire: Take a look at the link I included. It simply states that `The type argument must have a public parameterless constructor.` In other words, whatever you pass in as `T` must have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: I am using this code and just noticed that it returns a null object.